# from where add to cart code works

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new for the wordpress and I am using woocommerce plugin to create an ecommerce website through it.
           I want to know that from where the add to cart functionality is being taking place either by template or by some specific function invloved in attempting the add to cart functionality . I am searching for this as I have to add some custom fields other then provided by the woocommerce.

I have to add the field "material type and description" for the product which is being dynamically generated at the  client end.and I have to add that dynamically generated values to the cart and also I have to add this to the Database table as  well . so that it will be available through the checkout page.

Please hemp me to solve the Issue.

As I have search to display the cart "cart.php template "is available but it is not showing the code for add to cart.